# IP's from USA/UK

Tags: configuration

How do I edit Tor so as to make my IP look like coming from either USA or UK (exact edit)
I know its edited in 'torrc file' maybe if someone can show me a cut and paste solution - TQ

Answer (score 0):

In your torrc, add:

```
StrictExitNodes 1
ExitNodes {us},{uk}
```